# Youtube breaks down when I log in

Tags: youtube, google-signin

Something very strange happened tonight. I normally watched a videos on youtube, and when I clicked on the next I got this

[image: youtube]

[image: code]

I cleared the cache and everything else, and I could normally play video, but as soon as I log in, I get this kind of look. I tried to log in with multiple accounts and it's always the same. This is first time I got this kind of problems with youtube. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Update: I can log in on any other PC and works just fine...I tried reinstalling the Windows, and again same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And finally I found a solution. When I saw one more guy from Serbia on youtube community with the same problem, I realize that my country is a problem. So I went to google preferences, and change language to English. Now works fine.